# Standardizing dataframe with using for loops

Tags: standardization

```
survey_B <- data.frame("q1" = c(5, 3, 2, 7, 1, 9),
                   "q2" = c(4, 2, 2, 5, 1, 10),
                   "q3" = c(2, 1, 4, 2, 9, 10),
                   "q4" = c(10, 5, 2, 10, 4, 2),

sd_B2 <- t(apply(survey_B, 2, function(x) x/sd(x)))
mean_B2 <- t(apply(survey_B, 2, function(x) x/mean(x)))

for(i in 1:nrow(survey_B)) {
  for(j in 1:ncol(survey_B)) {
    survey_B[i,j] = survey_B[i,j]-mean_B2[i,j] / sd_B2[i,j]
   }
}
```

I would like to standardize my dataframe by using for loops. I get the mean and sd for columns, but I cannot divide the mean with the sd. I always receive an error message "out of boundaries".

Can someone advise me, please?

Comment: Hi Matthias! Welcome :) Could you provide a full error message output? It would also be useful to specify the language you are using and tag it.

Comment: Hi, thanks! :) The full message is: "Error in mean_B2[i, j] : subscript out of bounds" (And I have just noticed that I left a comma at "q4" line here. The message is after I deleted that comma.)